# SQL Query containing 2 result sets

Tags: mysql, sql

`select name from persons where gender = 'male' order by name limit 10`

`select name from persons where gender = 'female' order by name limit 10`

How can I get the first 10 males and the first 10 females in a single result set (20 entries) with a single SQL query call? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax uses parentheses and `union all`:

```
(select name
 from persons
 where gender = 'male'
 order by name
 limit 10
) union all
(select name
 from persons
 where gender = 'female'
 order by name
 limit 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and it's called `UNION`

Comment: Yes this implies that the one who's reading it has some brains and does not work for "Copy and Paste Software" LTD

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) Operator.

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.

```
select name from persons where gender = 'male' order by name limit 10
UNION
select name from persons where gender = 'female' order by name limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT name FROM persons WHERE gender = 'male' ORDER BY name LIMIT 0,10 ;
  UNION 
 SELECT name FROM persons WHERE gender = 'female' ORDER BY name LIMIT 0,10 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

with ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gender ORDER BY gender) row_no,*  FROM Person
) A WHERE A.row_no <= 10
```